# Passing variables through loops

Tags: java, loops, variables

I believe `x` is *global*, unfortunately I cannot share its value with `y` inside a loop within another loop.

public class A {

```
static int[] num = {1,4,1};
static int x , y;   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    firstLoop();
}

public static void firstLoop(){

    for (A.x = 0; A.x< num.length; A.x++ ) {

        System.out.println(" nums : " + num[A.x] );

                for ( A.y = A.x; A.y < num.length;A.y++) {

                    System.out.println(" for2 : " + A.x + " " + A.y);                   
                }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no idea what you're trying to do or what you're asking. Please take the time to add more details and a specific question. Please also take the time to format your code (and make **compilable** code), especially your braces.

Comment: Why you think so? And where is your question?

Comment: Write the complete code so that we can compile it. Then explain what error, exception or output you are getting, and what is the problem. We are unable to help without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can only access `static` values in `static` method

[image]

So you should change your non-static variables `int x, y` to `static int x, y` or you can access by creating an instance of  your class as :

```
public class B {

   int x,y;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b=new B();
        System.out.println(b.x+" "+b.y);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `y = x`, `x` is the loop variable, not the class one.

You can use `a.x` instead (where `a` is the class name) if you make `x` a static variable.

```
public class Example {
    private static int x;
    public static void access() {
        for (int x = 0; x < name.len[x]; x++) {
            for (int y = Example.x; y < text.len[y]; y++) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```